# What licence should I use for internal projects?

Tags: licensing

I need to package an internal project as a debian package. That project will never ever be downloaded by anyone outside of our company, but the debian packaging system insists on there being a `copyright` file.

What should I choose for this file? There's a remote possibility that a sysadmin could stumble upon that package and would like to read its licence. What should it then read?

Answer (score 14):

for internal code I would make the copyright file simply be a one line `copyright 'your company here'` licenses are for distribution of code and you aren't distributing. I would hope your sysadmin knows the name of your company.

Comment: +1 - `Copyright {Year} {Company Name}, all rights reserved` is the best thing to put.

Comment: You might add "For internal use only" to make the intention clear, might be relevant when using GPL or other license which allow free use but have restriction on redistribution and when the code leaks.

Answer (score 5):

Although it's likely that [Ryathal's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151925/4) is suitable in most instances, you might also want to consult your manager or legal department. There might be a standard template for projects. Although it's currently an internal product, it would be wise to have your company's standard copyright/license notice (if one exists) should it ever be released or sold in the future, or perhaps in a worse case gets leaked.